# What does 'twitter/facebook Town Hall' mean in Chinese?

Tags: translation, meaning

I watched the video ' Obama's Twitter Town Hall- Full Video ' in Youtube.But I knew the **Town Hall** means '市政厅',and what does it mean here?

Comment: It is actually a town hall meeting. The word "meeting" could have been dropped from the video title.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question appears to ask what "town hall" means in English. While asking for a Chinese equivalent is fine, this really looks more like an English language question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A town hall meeting is known as [市民大会](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%B8%82%E6%B0%91%E5%A4%A7%E4%BC%9A) or 市政厅会议. It has to be noted that this concept originates from [America](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Town_hall_meeting) and may not be well received in other countries depending on the political system.

A Facebook or a Twitter town hall meeting can be generally termed as 网上市民大会. An example sourced from [this](http://www.chinanews.com/gj/2011/04-21/2987476.shtml) news article reads:

> 中新社旧金山4月20日电(记者
>   刘丹)20日下午，美国总统奥巴马在加州帕洛阿图市的脸书(Facebook)总部举行“分担责任共享繁荣”**网上市民大会**时表示，希望更多有智慧有雄心的人留在美国，不希望看到下一个英特尔这样的企业在中国或法国创业。

Comment: 我好像记得公司的员工大会也用了这个，也可以用吗，我们是外企

Comment: 在其他方面如企业,英语词汇是有用到的(Stackoverflow Meta 里就有用到这词),但不正规。至于华语词汇我就不晓得了。

Comment: @liamxu In the companies I've worked for, 员工大会 is called "company meeting" or "all-hands meeting". "Town hall" is more of a Q/A session with managers that you are free to attend or not. Chinese translation is 与xxx面对面/见面会/问答会.

Comment: @liamxu If you like the answer, you should **upvote and accept the answer**. Otherwise, Mr. Overflow goes unrewarded for his hard work (except for my upvote).